# Stalk of a presheaf with values in arbitrary categories

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory

Let $\mathscr{F}$ be a presheaf over a topological space $X$ with values on a category $C$. We define the stalk of $\mathscr{F}$ at a point $p\in X$ as the colimit of all $\mathscr{F}(U)$ over all open sets $U$ containing $p$:
$$\mathscr{F}_p:=\varinjlim \mathscr{F}(U).$$

When $C$ is the category of sets, this has a simple description as
$$\left(\coprod_{U\ni x}\mathscr{F}(U)\right)\bigg/ \sim,$$
where $(f,U)\sim (g,V)$ if there is some open set $W\subset U\cap V$ containing $p$ such that $f|_W=g|_W$. If I understood correctly, people usually use the same description when $C$ is the category of abelian groups, for example. But isn't in this case the colimit given by the quocient of a direct sum instead?

If this same construction indeed works in the category of abelian groups, on which other categories does it also work? (Maybe in every concrete category? Every concrete category whose underlying set functor is conservative?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point here is that the forgetful functor $\mathbf{Ab\to Set}$ preserves filtered colimits, and that the colimit you're taking here is always filtered, so you get a description of that type, *with the set coproduct* (although you could also have a definition with direct sums)

This will work whenever your forgetful functor preserves filtered colimits, e.g. for rings, modules over a ring (or a sheaf of rings), ...

Comment: How would the description of the stalk (in Ab) with direct sums be?

Comment: Actually, exactly the same with $\coprod$ replaced with $\bigoplus$ (and of course you replace $\sim$ by the subgroup generated by $(f,U)-(g,V)$). It's instructive to figure out why !

Comment: Nice, I'll try that out. Do you know a simple criterion to know when the forgetful functor preserves filtered colimits? That does not seem obvious to me at all.

Comment: Mhm it is always the case when dealing with finitary algebraic theories (that's almost their definition actually, but what I mean is if you can write down a definition of a structure where each piece of data is a map $S_1\times ... \times S_n \to S$, $n<\infty$, and arrows are structure preserving maps, then it will work). Otherwise, I'm not sure there are very useful criteria unfortunately. If you know about monads, in a monadic situation, it's equivalent to the monad preserving filtered colimits